# Interpolation when no datarow exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
     Idnumber   Parent  Date             Other variables
      1         a       2005             x
      1         a       2007             x
      2         b       2005             x
      2         b       2006             x
      2         b       2007             x
```

I need it to look like this:

```
     Idnumber   Parent   Date          Other variables           
      1         a       2005             x          
      1         NaN     2006             NaN          
      1         a       2007             x         
      2         b       2005             x
      2         b       2006             x
      2         b       2007             x
```

Considering that I need to be able to perform checks on the added values later I cannot simply add them. I need to verify they did not exist and copy various remaining variables as well which will be interpolated. These need to come out empty.

My idea was to create an empty row between all existing rows and simply backwards and forwards fill. Thereby ensuring no other information was copied.
I would not know how to do this though.

Preferably I would skip the introduction of the empty row and do the whole thing in one go.
But I have even less of an idea how to get started on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For overall approach, you could first define which rows *should* exist and then merge with the original dataset.

```
>>> orig

   Idnumber Parent  Date Other
0         1      a  2005     x
1         1      a  2007     x
2         2      b  2005     x
3         2      b  2006     x
4         2      b  2007     x
```

Now use `itertools.product` to define all the rows that should exist.  (You could alternatively use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`.)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(orig['Idnumber'].unique(),
                                             orig['Date'].unique())))
>>> df.columns = ['Idnumber','Date']

   Idnumber  Date
0         1  2005
1         1  2006
2         1  2007
3         2  2005
4         2  2006
5         2  2007
```

Then merge with the original data:

```
>>> df.merge(orig,how='outer',on=['Idnumber','Date'])

   Idnumber  Date Parent Other
0         1  2005      a     x
1         1  2006    NaN   NaN
2         1  2007      a     x
3         2  2005      b     x
4         2  2006      b     x
5         2  2007      b     x
```

After this you can then use `fillna`, `interpolate`, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Will test (and accept) this afternoon, was not near my python pc this weekend.